# How to insert text starting with double quotes in a column delimited with | in a import command in db2

Tags: shell, import, db2, sh

Table contains 3 columns
ID -integer
Name-varchar
Description-varchar

A file with .FILE extension has data with delimiter as |
Eg: 12|Ramu|"Ramu" is an architect

Command I am using to load data to db2:
db2 "Load CLIENT FROM ABC.FILE of DEL MODIFIED BY coldel0x7x keepblanks REPLACE INTO tablename(ID,Name,Description) nonrecoverable"

Data is loaded as follows:
12 Ramu Ramu

but I want it as:
12 Ramu "Ramu" is an architect

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [how the format of delimited ASCII files is defined](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0004647.html). The double quote (`"`) is an optional delimited for character data. You would need to escape it. I have not tested it, but I would assume that you double the quote as you would do in SQL:

```
|12|Ramu|"""Ramu"" is an architect"
```

Delimited files (CSV) are defined in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). You need to either use quotes for the entire field or none at all. Only in fields beginning and ending with a quote, other quotes can be used. They need to be escaped as shown.

Comment: If I pass the data in the file with a space after delimiter as 12|ramu| "ramu" is an architect . Iam getting the output. But Is there any way to handle if the data in the file is 12|ramu|"ramu" is an architect

Comment: Here the delimiter is | (pipe symbol) . I want the quotes to appear in the db2 database table.

Comment: Had you use the quotes as shown in my answer?

Comment: Yes empty value got inserted in the third column

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `nochardel` modifier.
2. If you use '|' as a column delimiter, you must use `0x7C` and not `0x7x`:

   MODIFIED BY coldel0x7C keepblanks nochardel